# python code nested dictionary not producing output? no errors

Tags: python, compiler-errors

I am trying to run the code below. It is just simple lists and dictionaries I'm experimenting with, however it does not seem to produce any output when run I it and I cannot see where I have gone wrong.

I appreciate the code doesn't make much sense. I was just looking for arbitrary values like top trumps just to see if I could make something.

```
 bikes = {'mtb':{'sus':2, 'wheels':4},
   'bmx':{'sus':0, 'wheels':2},
   'road': {'sus':1,'wheels':4}}

 def totalItems(bikes,item):
    numItems =0
    for k, v in bikes.items():
        numItems= numItems +v.get(item, 0)
        return numItems

    print('number of items:')
     print('-sus  '+ str(totalItems(bikes,'sus')))
    print('-wheels  +str(totalItems(bikes,'wheels')))
```

Comment: Python does not complain about indentation problems right before the last line?

Comment: Your code never reaches `print` statements. Your function terminates as soon as it reaches 'return`. In Your case, it returns just after entering first run of for loop.

Comment: thanks all, i have made the suggested amendments and had some success, thanks again for your time

Answer (score 1):

I guess at the end of your code you have to call the function?...

```
totalItems(bikes, item)
```

Or for this example you mean?

```
bikes = {'mtb':{'sus':2, 'wheels':4},
  'bmx':{'sus':0, 'wheels':2},
  'road': {'sus':1,'wheels':4}}

def totalItems(bikes,item):
   numItems =0
   for k, v in bikes.items():
       numItems= numItems +v.get(item, 0)
   return numItems

print('number of items:')
print('-sus  ' + str(totalItems(bikes,'sus')))
print('-wheels ' + str(totalItems(bikes,'wheels')))
```

To move the print functions to out of the function?

Output:

```
number of items:
-sus  3
-wheels 10
```

Comment: yes i have some problems cutting and pasting to stack so it put my alignment out. however even aligned properly it seem to produce nothing? thanks

Comment: @C212 Check the last example, it should work, please accept and upvote if it works :)

Comment: return `numItems` should be outside of the loop else you get the wrong result.

Comment: @Corralien Ah thats true! thanks for telling me that, edited mine

Answer (score 1):

Your code lines are not well aligned:

```
bikes = {'mtb':{'sus':2, 'wheels':4},
  'bmx':{'sus':0, 'wheels':2},
  'road': {'sus':1,'wheels':4}}

def totalItems(bikes,item):
   numItems =0
   for k, v in bikes.items():
       numItems= numItems +v.get(item, 0)
   return numItems  # <- HERE

print('number of items:')  # <- HERE
print('-sus ' + str(totalItems(bikes,'sus')))  # <- HERE
print('-wheels ' + str(totalItems(bikes,'wheels')))  # <- HERE
```

Output:

```
number of items:
-sus 3
-wheels 10
```

You can use [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) to replace your last 2 `print` call to get more readibility:

```
print(f"-sus {totalItems(bikes,'sus')}")
print(f"-wheels {totalItems(bikes,'wheels')}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The code had problematic spaces before some lines and there was a missing quotation mark in the last line and the `return` was inside the `for loop` so it was terminating after the first iteration and returning without it completing adding the numbers.

Here's the code with proper indentations with an explaination after every fixed line,

```
    bikes = {'mtb':{'sus':2, 'wheels':4},
        'bmx':{'sus':0, 'wheels':2},
        'road': {'sus':1,'wheels':4}}

    def totalItems(bikes, item): # There was a space before 'def'
        numItems =0
        for k, v in bikes.items():
            numItems = numItems + v.get(item, 0)
        return numItems # The return needs to be outside of the loop
                        # so it won't terminate after the first iteration

    print('number of items:') # There were 4 spaces before 'print'
    print('-sus  '+ str(totalItems(bikes,'sus'))) # There were 5 spaces before 'print'
    print('-wheels '  + str(totalItems(bikes,'wheels'))) # There were 4 spaces before 'print'
                                                        # There was only one quotation mark before the word '-wheels' so it wasnt running correcly
```

Sugesstion:
In the last two lines you can use the `.format()` method to include the functions output inside the string. Here's how it would look

```
    print('-sus {}'.format(str(totalItems(bikes,'sus'))))
    print('-wheels {}'.format(str(totalItems(bikes,'wheels'))))
```

The `.format()` method formats the input that you put in it inside the curly brackets `{}` in the string.